# contingency table doesn't return the right result in r shiny with pickerInput

Tags: r, shiny, contingency

I'm trying to create a contingency table on r shiny using the function table() and a pickerInput. While I don't have any message error, the result I obtain on r shiny isn't right. The code and the data I tried are below:

```
#install.packages("shinydashboard")                   
library(shinydashboard)
#install.packages("DT")
library(DT)


data<-data.frame(Products=c("A","B","B","B","A","B","A","A","B"),
                 Clients=c("c1","c1","c2","c3","c3","c3","c3","c3","c3"))

ui<-fluidPage(
  box(title="croisement client/produit",status = "info", solidHeader = TRUE, width = 12,
      fluidRow(pickerInput('select_Product','Choisir les produits', choices=as.character(unique(data$Products)), selected = "A", options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),multiple =T),
                      DT::dataTableOutput("tab_prod"))
      )
)


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  table1<-function(data){
    data_intermediaire<-data[(data$Products==input$select_Product),]
    objet_etudie<-as.data.frame.matrix(table(data_intermediaire$Product,data_intermediaire$Clients))
    return(objet_etudie)
  }
  
  output$tab_prod<-DT::renderDataTable({datatable(table1(data))})
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I choose the product "A" with the pickerInput it is the right result but when I choose product A and product B the result is :

```
    C1  C2
A   1   2
B   1   2
```

while it should be:

```
    C1  C2
A   1   3
B   1   4
```

When I use the table without r shiny with this code:

```
data<-data.frame(Products=c("A","B","B","B","A","B","A","A","B"),
                 Clients=c("c1","c1","c2","c3","c3","c3","c3","c3","c3"))
data_intermediaire<-data[(data$Products=="A")|(data$Products=="B"),]
objet_etudie<-as.data.frame.matrix(table(data_intermediaire$Product,data_intermediaire$Clients))
```

,I have the right answer. So this makes me think that maybe I didn't really understand how the pickerInput works...

Thank you in advance for your advices.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
library(shiny)

data<-data.frame(Products=c("A","B","B","B","A","B","A","A","B"),
                 Clients=c("c1","c1","c2","c3","c3","c3","c3","c3","c3"))

ui<-fluidPage(
    box(title="croisement client/produit",status = "info", solidHeader = TRUE, width = 12,
        fluidRow(pickerInput('select_Product','Choisir les produits', choices=as.character(unique(data$Products)), selected = "A", options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),multiple =T),
                 DT::dataTableOutput("tab_prod"))
    )
)


server <- function(input, output,session) {
    
    table1 <- function(data,select_Product){
        data_intermediaire<-data[(data$Products %in% select_Product),]
        objet_etudie<-as.data.frame.matrix(table(data_intermediaire$Product,data_intermediaire$Clients))
        return(objet_etudie)
    }
    
    output$tab_prod <- DT::renderDataTable({
        
        datatable(table1(data,input$select_Product))
        
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```